# Do you know a video plugin that allows embedding in the home.php file?

Tags: plugins

I've been looking for a video plugin in the plugin depository but couldn't find one that I'm looking for.

Basically, I want visitors to be able to play the video in the home page but the issue here is that the home page is displaying post excerpts. So if I would just post the video as normal, it would be cut in the home page.

So I think I would need to hard code the video code of the plugin inside the loop in the home template file, like  where $video is the the video file in the post.

Does anybody know a video plugin like this?

Or is there a work around here, like how to show video in the home page having post excepts.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The excerpt is not meant for content that is why it is called "the excerpt".

Instead use a plugin like "Vipers Video Quicktags" or "Youtube shortcode" and add it to a template file and you'll probably want to get the url via a post meta field.

for example ( using Youtube shortcode plugin and meta field called "video"):

```
$video = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'video', true);
echo do_shortcode('[youtube_sc url='$video']');
```

Comment: Yeah, this is what I was looking for! But I did need to change the quotes to read like this: echo do_shortcode("[youtube_sc url=$video]");

Answer (score 0):

My idea may be tricky to put in practice (hope not impossible!), but you can add a filter for `the_excerpt` or `get_the_excerpt` and, since you are in the loop you may be able to find the post ID using the global `$post` or query var in your function, then, get the entire content of the post, find the videos and add them at the beginning or at the end of the excerpt.